# Parser for gleaning data from twitter

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, twitter, selenium

I've written a script in python to parse the name, tweets, following and follower of those people available in view all section in my profile page of twitter. My scraper is able to parse those aforesaid fields flawlessly. Any input on the improvement of my parser will be highly appreciated. Here is what I've written:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def browsing_pages():

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://twitter.com/?lang=en')

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="signin-email"]').send_keys('username')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="signin-password"]').send_keys('password')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]').click()
    time.sleep(5)

    #Clicking the viewall link
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//small[@class='view-all']//a[contains(@class,'js-view-all-link')]").click()
    time.sleep(5)

    for links in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='stream-item-header']//a[contains(@class,'js-user-profile-link')]"):
        scraping_docs(links.get_attribute("href"))
        #tracking down each profile links under viewall section

def scraping_docs(item_link):

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(item_link)

    # gleaning information of each profile holder
    for prof in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='route-profile']"):
        name = prof.find_elements_by_xpath(".//h1[@class='ProfileHeaderCard-name']//a[contains(@class,'ProfileHeaderCard-nameLink')]")[0]
        tweet = prof.find_elements_by_xpath(".//span[@class='ProfileNav-value']")[0]
        following = prof.find_elements_by_xpath(".//span[@class='ProfileNav-value']")[1]
        follower = prof.find_elements_by_xpath(".//span[@class='ProfileNav-value']")[2]
        print(name.text, tweet.text, following.text, follower.text)

        driver.quit()

browsing_pages()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd focus on 3 main things:

- **don't use `time.sleep()` to wait for elements on a page**. With hardcoded time delays there is a *tendency to wait more than actually needed* most of the time and less than needed sometimes - not reliable at all. Instead, use [Explicit Waits with `WebDriverWait` class](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) and a set of Expected Conditions
- remove the **overhead of firing up a separate Chrome instance** - collect the links into a list a reuse the same WebDriver instance - you should expect improvements in page load times as well
- **improve your locators** - XPath locators are generally the slowest - use "by id" locators whenever possible; handling `class` attributes with CSS selectors is more reliable (raw `contains()` in XPath may generate false positives - [it can be a bit better with `concat()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1390680/771848))

In the end, you should have something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def browsing_pages(driver):
    driver.get('https://twitter.com/login')
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('form.signin input.email-input').send_keys('username')
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('form.signin input.js-password-field').send_keys('password')
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('form.signin button[type=submit]').click()

    view_all = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".view-all a.js-view-all-link")))
    view_all.click()

    # wait for a profile link to become visible
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".stream-item-header a.js-user-profile-link")))

    links = [link.get_attribute("href") for link in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".stream-item-header a.js-user-profile-link")]
    for link in links:
        scraping_docs(driver, link)


def scraping_docs(driver, item_link):
    driver.get(item_link)

    # gleaning information of each profile holder
    for prof in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".route-profile"):
        name = prof.find_element_by_css_selector("h1.ProfileHeaderCard-name a.ProfileHeaderCard-nameLink")
        tweet = prof.find_element_by_css_selector(".ProfileNav-value")

        _, following, follower = prof.find_elements_by_css_selector(".ProfileNav-value")[:3]
        print(name.text, tweet.text, following.text, follower.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    try:
        browsing_pages(driver)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

You may also go for a class with the driver instance kept at `self.driver`, but I think it's pretty much okay to do it this "functional" way considering that you have only two functions. Good read on the subject:

- [Stop Writing Classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0)
- [Start Writing More Classes](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2013/2/13/moar-classes/)

Comment: Omg!! Who did I get response from!! It's always a great pleasure to have you in the loop sir, alecxe. I just executed your code. However, it breaks when it hits the line containing "links = [link.get_attribute("href") for link----". I suppose you wanna take a look. Thanks again sir.

Comment: @SMth80 thanks, yeah, we keep stumbling upon each other on multiple SE forums :) Thanks for the good question! How does it fail?

Comment: @SMth80 I've added a wait before grabbing the links - might help - if you meant by "breaks" that it could not find the links to follow (with no errors). Thanks.

Comment: This is the very message I'm getting. " raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document". Forgive my ignorance.

Comment: @SMth80 no problem, let's fix it - on which line does it fail? (I'll be afk for a bit)

Comment: Sir alecxe, console indicates line 21 which is:"links = [link.get_attribute("href") for link in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".stream-item-header a.js-user-profile-link")]".

Comment: @SMth80 ah, have you modified the code I've posted by any chance? It is important to first grab all the links and only then process them..

Comment: Nope, sir. I didn't do anything to your code. I'm just waiting for the time you will be free and take a look. Thanks sir.

Comment: That Jack Diederich video is one of my all time favourites, I show it to Java people all the time ;D

Comment: @SMth80 I've tried to make the code work and it actually worked for me almost as is - the only changes I made was the initial "login" step - navigated to a "login" page and changed the locators of the input fields. Please re-check. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks sir, for your answer. I've just checked with your updated code. Getting the same error again. Here is the link to see the error: "https://www.dropbox.com/s/iswkg2aii2r7nyh/Execution%20Error.txt?dl=0"

Comment: @SMth80 no problem, I guess the streaming nature of the page affects the behavior of this webdriver test automation script. Does adding a `time.sleep(5)` before getting the links help? (not the best solution, of course - more like a workaround until we can think of a better way to handle it) The problem is that I cannot reproduce the issue..

Comment: @SMth80 well, the problem described there on SO is clear - you are finding a link, getting an attribute and then navigate to the link from the current page. Then, after you are done processing the link, you are trying to get the next link, but you are already on a different page. That's why I noted that it's important to get the list of links first - before processing them..hope it is clear..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60317/discussion-between-alecxe-and-smth80).

Comment: Dear sir alecxe, in your spare time I suppose you wanna take a look into the problem described here cause along with several programs you are an expert on selenium as well. "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44560727/unable-to-parse-table-using-selenium"

Comment: Hi sir alecxe! I thought that I should give it a try once again and bam!! it worked for the first time flawlessly meeting the expectation. However, i could not make it work when i tried the second, third----- time. As it worked in my first try, I suppose there should be any technical problem out there somewhere. Anyways, in your spare time, please give it a look if it is possible to fix it permanently. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SMth80 no problem! Just to not "pollute" the comments here - could you please create an SO questions with details about the code you are executing and the stacktrace of the error you are getting. Thanks! Please throw me a link here as well.